# Get data only from line and column that contains specific prerequisite (Output View)

Tags: powershell

I would like to know how to get string(s) from line that containing specific value so other lines would be ignored.

From the example below I need to get string from column "Name" and from line only that contains word "MyPC"

This is just example, it's only to show an idea.

```
$Computer = "MyPC" 
$Group = Get-WmiObject win32_group -ComputerName $Computer
| ? {$_.SID -eq 'S-1-5-32-544'}

Caption                    Domain     Name               SID
-------                    ------     ----               ----
MyPC\Administratoren       MyPC       Administratoren    S-1-5-32-544
DOMAIN\Administratoren     DOMAIN     Administratoren    S-1-5-32-544
```

Using this particular example I would like to get data from 1st line because it contains word "MyPC" and 3rd column. Anyone knows how could I do this?

Other option would be get data from 3rd column and if 2nd column contains "MyPc".

Actually both scripts would be awesome.

Comment: Share what you have tried until now and where are you facing problem. This is just asking someone to work for you w/o making an effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I don't understood your question, you want this?

```
$Group = Get-WmiObject win32_group -ComputerName $Computer
| ? {$_.SID -eq 'S-1-5-32-544' -and $_.domain -eq 'MyPC'} | select name
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted when I asked "Other option would be get data from 3rd column and if 2nd column contains "MyPc". Thanks for swift answer!

Comment: I used -ExpandProperty name to get exactly value named "Administratoren".

Comment: @user2667547 Glad to help. And yes `-expandproperty` fill better your need!